# Avro encoded binary to file

Tags: json, bash, avro, jq

Avro tools `tojson` command escapes binary values. Here's an example:

```
{"bytes":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002@ol\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@f¸\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@o¦\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@fú\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"}
```

How can I extract these binary values to file in bash? Is it possible using `jq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq's -r command-line option converts a JSON string to its "raw" form, so to convert the string in `.bytes`, you could pipe the JSON to:

```
jq -r .bytes
```

The occurrence of NULs in your sample makes it impossible to show the output here on SO.

Comment: Funny, I've never stopped to wonder why the "remove double quotes from strings" flag was `-r`. "Raw" makes sense. :)